# .Net Core Entity Framework Email Confirmation 'Click Here' link does not update 'EmailConfirmed' DB property

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I have setup SendGrid for my user registration email confirmation in my .Net 5.0 app as per Microsoft's instructions here: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=532713

Everything works fine until the user clicks the confirmation link in their register confirmation email.

**This issue is being caused by a stray amp in my confirmation link. I am trying to understand where it is coming from and how to remove it.**

When the new user clicks 'Submit' on the `Register.cshtml` page they are successfully directed to the `RegisterConfirmation.cshtml` page and the email is received in their inbox.

**Actual behavior:**

The user clicks the link in the email and hits the `ConfirmEmail` page.

The user is redirected to `/Index` page.

The `EmailConfirmed` bool in the DB is not updated.

If I comment out the redirect to /Index in my controller, then I get a null value error shown below.

```
//if (userId == null || code == null)
//{
//    return RedirectToPage("/Index", new { culture });
//}
```

[image: Null value error]

However, the query tab shows that the userId and code are correct.
[image]

**Expected behavior:**

The user clicks the link in the email.

The `EmailConfirmed` bool in the DB **IS** updated.

The user sees the `ConfirmEmail` page with the success message.

**ConfirmEmail.cshtml.cs**

```
    using System;
snip...
    
    namespace MyApp.Areas.Identity.Pages.Account
    {
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public class ConfirmEmailModel : PageModel
        {
            private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
            private readonly ISharedCultureLocalizer _loc;
            private readonly string culture;
            readonly ConfirmEmailPageLocSourceNames _locSourceConfirmEmailPageNameReferenceLibrary = new ConfirmEmailPageLocSourceNames();
            readonly SharedCrossPageLocSourceNames _locSourceSharedCrossPageNameReferenceLibrary = new SharedCrossPageLocSourceNames();
    
            public ConfirmEmailModel(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager, ISharedCultureLocalizer loc)
            {
                _userManager = userManager;
                _loc = loc;
                culture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name;
            }
    
            [TempData]
            public string StatusMessage { get; set; }
snip...
    
            public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync(string userId, string code)
            {
snip...
    
                if (userId == null || code == null)
                {
                    return RedirectToPage("/Index", new { culture });
                }
    
                var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(userId);
                if (user == null)
                {
                    var msg = _loc.GetLocalizedString("Unable to load user with ID '{0}'.", userId);
                    return NotFound(msg);
                }
    
                code = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(WebEncoders.Base64UrlDecode(code));
                var result = await _userManager.ConfirmEmailAsync(user, code);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    var msg = _loc.GetLocalizedString("Thank you for confirming your email.");
                    TempData.Success(msg);
                }
                else
                {
                    var msg = _loc.GetLocalizedString("Error confirming your email.");
                    TempData.Danger(msg);
                }
                return Page();
            }
        }
    }
```

**RegisterConfirmation.cshtml.cs**

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
snip...

namespace MyApp.Areas.Identity.Pages.Account
{
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public class RegisterConfirmationModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
        private readonly IEmailSender _sender;
        readonly RegisterConfPageLocSourceNames _locSourceRegisterConfPageNameReferenceLibrary = new RegisterConfPageLocSourceNames();
        readonly SharedCrossPageLocSourceNames _locSourceSharedCrossPageNameReferenceLibrary = new SharedCrossPageLocSourceNames();

        public RegisterConfirmationModel(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager, IEmailSender sender)
        {
            _userManager = userManager;
            _sender = sender;
        }

        public string Email { get; set; }
 snip...

        public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync(string email)
        {
            PageTabTitle = _locSourceRegisterConfPageNameReferenceLibrary.GetLocSourcePageTabTitleNameReferenceForRegisterConfPage();
 snip...

            if (email == null)
            {
                return RedirectToPage("/Index");
            }

            var user = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(email);
            if (user == null)
            {
                return NotFound($"Unable to load user with email '{email}'.");
            }

            Email = email;

            return Page();
        }
    }
}
```

**Register.cshtml.cs**

```
            var code = await _userManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user);
            Debug.WriteLine("**************** " + code);
            code = WebEncoders.Base64UrlEncode(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(code));
            Debug.WriteLine("**************** 1 *** " + code);
            var callbackUrl = Url.Page("/Account/ConfirmEmail", pageHandler: null, values: new { area = "Identity", userId = user.Id, code = code, culture }, protocol: Request.Scheme);

            var mailHeader = _loc.GetLocalizedString("Confirm your GatheringForGood email");
            var mailBody = _loc.GetLocalizedString(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name, "Please confirm your GatheringForGood account by <a href='{0}'>clicking here</a>.", HtmlEncoder.Default.Encode(callbackUrl));
                await _emailSender.SendEmailAsync(Input.Email, mailHeader, mailBody);
```

**Functions in EmailSender.cs**

```
public Task SendEmailAsync(string email, string subject, string message)
{
    return Execute(Options.SendGridKey, subject, message, email);
}

public Task Execute(string apiKey, string subject, string message, string email)
{
    var client = new SendGridClient(apiKey);
    var msg = new SendGridMessage()
    {
        From = new EmailAddress("info@myemail.com", Options.SendGridUser),
        Subject = subject,
        PlainTextContent = message,
        HtmlContent = message
    };
    msg.AddTo(new EmailAddress(email));

    // Disable click tracking.
    // See https://sendgrid.com/docs/User_Guide/Settings/tracking.html
    msg.SetClickTracking(false, false);

    return client.SendEmailAsync(msg);
}
```

**Update:**

In the callback string from my logs it says

```
userId=362c17ae-7854-42fb-91c3-efb19cc875f2&code=
```

But the link received in gmail says

```
userId=362c17ae-7854-42fb-91c3-efb19cc875f2&amp;code=
```

Tested in Postman and this is definitely the issue. I need the link in the email body to look like this. Notice there is no amp;

```
https://localhost:44305/en/Identity/Account/ConfirmEmail?userId=d62d4727-f6ce-493c-bcf3-eb85a50a914f&code=Q2ZESjhKbkE2NU5BVk85S2drRnMvV3VtZXBySVFlTHZrQlNvUU9xbUxrYWQ5NjFDV0NvZGY1eHVCK01SSHVIL3EwMjEwYk8rU1lLaHJ4UHF1VS84RjJQTThBWlY4VHZTcGcrQVpiZU9wWHFyWnlsVkFpSFVUV3lIMGJjaG14aFJKQkgxNjZoQkVNM3ZETnR2WHhoZmx0ZnhQR095azdDREJVZVdJN01CTTRCcFptejJvSURjNHloZHdxRDl0UCs0eEdic1NMK25wbnFqb0xhdHFoR3M3T3BkTElhbG5TVU9obTJaTFpvc0xUb0RINzM2UmFBTVlrakZWL2VsV0YvUEJSaE1HQT09
```

Comment: You have to write the code to do the update. Stack Overflow does not exist to do that for you.

Comment: That comment is distinctly unhelpful. I followed Microsofts instructions for the Identity Framework email confirmation and it is not working. I have tried figuring it out myself but Im stumped.

Comment: 'Entity Framework' scaffolded Identity pages.

Comment: @DMur - you never indicate that you are using Entity Framework **UI** where a lot of stuff is scaffolded for you. Giving the link to fourth (or whatever) lesson in the tutorial expects too much from the reader! I think your question is valid, but worth rewriting...

Comment: Sorry for the confusion @IanKemp

Comment: `&amp;` in html is perfectly fine usually. It is happening because you call `HtmlEncoder.Default.Encode..` on url in your `Register.cshtml`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed!
I just had to remove the Html encoding from my mailBody string population in the end.

I replaced:

```
var mailBody = _loc.GetLocalizedString(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name, "Please confirm your GatheringForGood account by <a href='{0}'>clicking here</a>.", HtmlEncoder.Default.Encode(callbackUrl));
```

With:

```
var mailBody = _loc.GetLocalizedString(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name, "Please confirm your GatheringForGood account by <a href='" + callbackUrl + "'>clicking here</a>.");
```

Thank you for all your help.

Answer (score 1):

it looks like the variable that has value is *amp;code*; **not** code. Do you have 2 ampersands somewhere by any chance? Yes you do -

```
b3a&amp;code=Q2ZE
```

Figure out why your code is generating such erroneous link in the confirmation email

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the generated link is also encoding the `&` between query string params in the confirmation URL:

```
// This is the problem
...&amp;code=Q2ZESjhKb...

//it should be lilke below
...&code=Q2ZESjhKb...
```

Comment: I do not have an ampersand in the link generation code. Update 2 above.

Comment: you can find it there in the `callback` string

Comment: Hmmm... in the callback string from my logs it says userId=362c17ae-7854-42fb-91c3-efb19cc875f2&code= but in the link received in gmail it says userId=362c17ae-7854-42fb-91c3-efb19cc875f2&amp;code=

Comment: Check the email sending middleware (was it SendGrid?), there should be some options for encoding the email body or define its format as html.

Comment: Although I dont know where that & in my logs is coming from. There is no ampersand symbol at the end of the userId value. Perhaps it should just be 875f2code=

Comment: Fixed. Although I haven't checked the localization yet.